# What is a question page's title made up of?

Tags: discussion, tags

Take a look at this image:

[image: Title relating to tag]

It appears the page's title's is made up of `someTag, dash, question title`, but what tag is `someTag`?  This question has three tags, yet it shows the `singlepage` tag out of all three, so what is the tag that appears in the page's title and why?

Comment: I think it's the first tag that isn't already in the title.

Comment: Voted to close my own question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first or second top tag (sorted by popularity) not already in the title is prepended. If both tags are already in the title, no tag is prepended at all.

For example, [How to use eval instead if else in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000449/how-to-use-eval-instead-if-else-in-python) has has *python* in the title, so the lone [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag on the post doesn't make it into the title of the page.

In another example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000942/python-implement-cli-in-shell-and-telnet, both top tags are already in the title, the 3rd tag is not considered.

Comment: What do you mean by `first`, first in chronological order?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet: sorted by popularity of the tag at the time of last edit. If tag popularity has changed over time an edit could lead to a reordering of the tags shown on a post, and thus what tag ends up in the title.

Comment: Oh okay (will accept when I can).

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to accept a year later